# Xaml parser exception

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

This is something that's driving me crazy.. I have a WPF project which is already in production. Now, I have to make some fix for which I have to set x:Name property to couple of controls. But, when I set x:Name property for **any** control, it's throwing XamlParser exception (inner exception says cannot cast type XXX to type Button where XXX is type of control for which I am setting x:Name property).

It also shows an additional error like,

**Additional information: Set connectionId threw an exception.**

I have closed and reopened Visual Studio; I have cleaned the solution and rebuilt many times; but no use.

Can anybody let mw know what's going on?

Here is the code - I have just added x:Name = "PnlUpDown" to stack panel.

```
<StackPanel Name="PnlUpDown" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="3">
            <Button x:Name="BtnMoveUp" Padding="3,5" Margin="5,0,0,3" Tag="MOVEUP" >
                <Polygon Points="0,15 5,0,10,15" Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"/>
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="BtnMoveDown" Padding="3,5" Margin="5,3,0,0" Tag="MOVEDOWN" >
                <Polygon Points="0,0 5,15,10,0" Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}"/>
            </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

**Now.. I find that not only x:Name property.. It's not allowing me to set any other property to any control - In general, if I modify my XAML it's throwing error..!!!!!!! For everything it's throwing Set Connection Id error  :(**

Comment: post your xaml code please..

Comment: Try using "Name" instead of "x:Name" it might work and functionally makes no difference

Comment: @Yuliam - I have updated my original post with code.
bathineni - I tried using just 'Name' but it's the same.

Comment: the code works fine at my pc, what is the exact error message? and check the project reference that might missing

Comment: What are you using these names for? Also, look at the inner exception.

Comment: How is the "x" namespace declared?

Comment: x is regular wpf namespace. Outer Exception says Set Connection threw exception. Inner exception tells that there is a type cast exception. But note that, if I remove the Name="PnlUpDown" then everything works fine.. Please re-read my original post which I have modified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how it's related but I just restarted my machine and the issue got resolved !!!! May be Visual Studio 2013 gets refreshed when the machine reboots.. I don't know. Anyways, Thanks everyone for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

First, check out this post:  [How do you debug a XamlParseException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879312/how-do-you-debug-a-xamlparseexception).  Specifically, look at the call stack as noted in the answer by Igor Zevaka.

Also check the answers to the following questions:

- [XamlParseException after deploying WPF project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615597/xamlparseexception-after-deploying-wpf-project)
- [xamlParseException on window launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970706/xamlparseexception-on-window-launch)

`XamlParseException` can be one of the more difficult exceptions to find.  If none of those point you in the right direction, look at the code-behind and the data context.  Perhaps there is an exception being thrown in one of those locations.

Comment: Thank you. I went through those links. But no use. Actually the same project is VS2013 and VS2010 (exact copies except prior one targets 4.5 framework and later one targets 3.5). If I make the changes in later one, it works fine. But 2013 one gives problem. May be some bug in VS2013.