# Silverlight 5 app works on 32 bit IE but crashes on 64 bit IE

Tags: internet-explorer, silverlight

I am using IE 11 on a 64 bit Windows 8.1 OS.

I have accessed a silverlight application which on a 64 bit IE browser crashes when I am do some task. I get:

```
SCRIPT5022: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Code: 4004    
Category: ManagedRuntimeError       
Message: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: [Parser_CreateInstance_ConstructorInvocation]
```

However doing the same task on a IE 32 bit browser does not crash.

Any ideas why this can be occurring?

Thanks

Comment: What is the runtime version of the Silverlight plugin you installed?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am checking with the customer, is there a buggy version out there?

Comment: This could maybe be helpful to get more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879312/how-do-you-debug-a-xamlparseexception

Comment: @RomanCanlas : Version is 5.1.30214.0

Comment: Can you try to reinstall? latest I believe is 5.1.30514.0